# Python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Aditya Bhatt\\Desktop\\Aditya\\SampleData.csv'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

So, here's my code...

```
filename = r"C:\Users\Aditya Bhatt\Desktop\Aditya\SampleData.csv" 
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Now, it shows me this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\Aditya Bhatt\Desktop\Aditya\SampleData.csv'

The file location is: "C:\Users\Aditya Bhatt\Desktop\Aditya"[Confirmed]
Name of File: SampleData (.csv file)

I'm running the code on Google Colab
Also, I got this file from the internet (If that helps)

Comment: you cant access local files from "Google Colab" directly. You would need to go through alternative routes. if you are on Colab, on the left side you will see a "Files" menu, you can upload the file through it. And then you can run some commands like `import os
print(os.listdir())` to understand what you got in the directory. hope this will help otherwise feel free to ask further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go.
[How to deal with local files in Google Colab](https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files)

Since a Colab notebook is hosted on Google’s cloud servers, there’s no direct access to files on your local drive (unlike a notebook hosted on your machine) or any other environment by default.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put double back slashes `\\` instead of single `\`

so it should be like this:

C:\something\assd\dada\x.csv